# Kissmetrics data scraping

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, metrics, kissmetrics

Kissmetrics is a pretty cool package, but doesn't offer the ability to build your own widgets off their "metrics" that you create on your dashboard.  I have been doing some investigation and it looks like after page load, some js wizardry happens that returns some data and the metrics widgets are written to.

I was trying to read through the js to find out where the data was being pulled from or when it was being written, but it was a pain to parse visually.

Is there any way to figure out where js is pulling data via AJAX for this?  I would expect it to appear in the Net or Console tab in Firebug, but it doesn't unfortunately.

Any help with this would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably moved on already, but I've found a working solution based on a solution outlined in this [blog post](http://www.j-ro.me/kissmetrics-for-lifecycle-emails.html). Some of it is already outdated, because they're updating their code, but the basics are there:

1. Find out where to send requests
2. Sign your requests
3. Make a sequence of requests to a certain URL

Kissmetrics also implements most of their URL-generation code in JS, which is very readable if you know where to look. I highly recommend looking at the network inspector while making some requests, and you'll be able to reverse-engineer from there. I've also built a ruby gem for this, in addition to the PHP script in that blog post, which will hopefully be available soon.

Comment: I'm the author of the blog post you mention.
The code was available from the start but was hidden in a text link in the article.
I added a big fat download button for clarity. You said it is already outdated, care to provide more details?

Comment: @jdangu A couple things in particular, mostly around signature generation. Newlines are now removed from the sha512. Also the "weird" URL encode you do is unnecessary. There might be other changes that I didn't notice because of the PHP->Ruby port. Do you still get valid data? Since I don't, using your script